# Deprecated for blocks.getSaveElement

Tags: block-editor

I wonder if there is the deprecated for `blocks.getSaveElement` hook?

First, I wrote the code like below.

```
const addWrapper = (el, type, attributes) => {
    if ('myblock/example' === type.name) {
        return <div className={"example"}>el<div>;
    } else {
        return el
    }
};
addFilter('blocks.getSaveElement', 'block/example', addWrapper);
```

Then, I want to change the wrapper element, but this hooks still affect to deprecated blocks.
I read the document https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/ but, I can not find the solution.
Is there an any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by myself. The detail is here.
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/28509